# My data is changing in frontend only while I'm using CRUD operation in angular and mongodb, after refresh it is again set to default value

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, api, mongoose

My data is switching to default value once I refresh the page and the value is not changing in mongoDB as I'm using Rest API.

**Below is the Backend code I'm using for updating data in Rest API.**

```
router.put('/:id',(req,res)=>{
  if(!ObjectId.isValid(req.params.id))
     return res.status(400).send(`No record with given id:${req.params.id}`)

     let emp = {
     firstName: req.body.firstName,
     lastName: req.body.lastName,
     relationship: req.body.relationship,
     dob:req.body.dob,
     ssn:req.body.ssn,
     memberid:req.body.memberid,
     status:req.body.status,
     };

     Employee.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,{$set:emp},{new :true},(err,doc)=>{
       if(!err){
          res.send(doc);
       }
       else{
          console.log('error in Employee update:' +JSON.stringify(err,undefined,2))
       }
     })
})
module. Exports = router;
```

**Below is the Backend code of SERVICE FILE.**

```
export class UsersDataService {
  selectedEmployee: Employee;
  statusChanged:any='';
  userSel:any={};
  searchResult:any='';
  userObj:any=[];
  baseURL ='http://localhost:8000/employees/'
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { 
  }

  users(){
     this.http.get(this.baseURL).subscribe((res) => {
      this.userObj = res ;
     })
  }

  updateUser(user:any){
    console.log(user);
    this.http.put(this.baseURL + user._id,user).subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data);
    })
  }
}
```

**Below is the code of HTML component**

```
    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm bb"(click)="enrollUser(user)"> Enroll</button> </td>
```

**Below is the code of ts file of the component**

```
enroll = false;
userSelected:any={};
unEnroll = false;
unenrolluser ='active';

constructor(public usersData:UsersDataService) {
}


 enrollUser(data:any){
      console.log(data);
      data.status = this.unenrolluser;
      this.userSelected = data;

    
      this.enroll = true;
      this.usersData.updateUser(this.userSelected)

  }
```

I want once I click on Enroll button the status will change to Active both in frontend and backend.
Means the data will update in the database too, in my case rest api should also gets updated.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

**In Service File return the the request response:**

```
  updateUser(user:any){
    console.log(user);
    return this.http.put(this.baseURL + user._id,user);
    }
```

**and then subscribe in the Component and update the Entity:**

```
 enrollUser(data:any){
      console.log(data);
      data.status = this.unenrolluser;
      this.userSelected = data;
      this.enroll = true;
      this.usersData.updateUser(this.userSelected).subscribe(res => 
      this.userSelected = res);
      }
```

hope it works for you.

Comment: No, it's not working. I want to update the status in database too but with this code once i refresh the code it set to default value again i.e. status sets back to inactive.

Comment: You want update the status of the user ?

Comment: Yes once click on enroll ..update the status

Comment: i think the Problem is that you are using the Variable this.enroll to change the status. What you should do is to use the Objekt that comes from your Database and refer to the status in that object. Like so `<div>{{userSelected.status}}</div>`